# How to fill numpy array with different numbers using iterative loops without duplication in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration

I Want to make an array like this form.

```
arr =[[1 2 3 4],
      [1 2 3 4],
      [2 2 3 4],
      [5 5 5 4]]
```

I have five arrays for this.

```
   arr0= [[0 0 0 0],
          [0 0 0 0],
          [0 0 0 0],
          [0 0 0 0]]

   arr1= [[1],
          [1]]

   arr2= [[0 2],
          [0 2],
          [2 2]]

   arr3= [[3],
          [3],
          [3]] 

   arr4= [[4],
          [4],
          [4],
          [4]] 

   arr5= [[5],[5],[5]]
```

But the problem is the sequence of the array are not given. 
Also, there are not allowed duplication of the array.
In this case, how can make right fit array form using iterative loops?

I was thinking using this function and index slicing,

```
#  Usage:
#  addAtPos(xycoor)
#    - mat1  : matrix to be added
#    - mat2  : add this matrix to mat1
#    - xycoor: tuple (x,y) containing coordinates
def addAtPos(mat1, mat2, xycoor):
    size_x, size_y = np.shape(mat2)
    coor_x, coor_y = xycoor
    end_x, end_y   = (coor_x + size_x), (coor_y + size_y)
    mat1[coor_x:end_x, coor_y:end_y] = mat1[coor_x:end_x, coor_y:end_y] + mat2
    return mat1
```

but it's really difficult to make perfect form..
please help me!

Comment: So, you want to solve a puzzle, basically?

Comment: Yes! I want to solve a puzzle ! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an optimization problem, and it can get very difficult.

Using only a simple loop you are going to get stuck, so at some point you will have to go back some moves and redo them at a different position.

One thing you can try is using a tree to keep track of the possible moves and the moves done to far. Also starting by using the "big" pieces will allow you to do some early pruning on the tree.

Example:

Take the 4 matrix as the first one. You have only 4 possible places to put it: column 1,2,3 or 4, so you create 4 branches from the root node.

Now if you take the piece 5, you can see that it will not fit anywhere if your first move was in the columns 1,2 or 3. So this will allow you to prone this branches. Now you know for sure that matrix 4 goes in the 4th column.

Similarly, at deeper levels you will discard positions for other pieces until you find a leaf of your tree (a node where all your pieces fit the matrix).

Note however that if the matrix is too big or you have too many pieces, this algorithm might take too long to solve the problem.

Comment: Wow.. Thank you so much! Actually, I also considered DFS(Depth First Traversal) but, I have no idea how to make a graph for this problem to use DFS code... T_T